# Search for recipes that contain a specific ingredient using Google Recipe

Tags: google-search

How does one search for recipes that contain a specific ingredient, in this case "tomato sauce", using Google Recipes?

I do not want to specify the recipe name, just the ingredients.

```
https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&prmdo=1&tbs=rcp%3A1%2Crcp_ing0%3Atomatoe+sauce&q=*&btnG=Search&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=
```

The above URL specifies the desired ingredient, "tomato sauce".

How does one indicate the wildcard nature for the search box?

Answer (score 1):

Try a plain Google search with terms *recipes using tomato sauce*.  After the initial results are returned, you can click the "Recipes" button on the left to be more selective.

Added via edit:

As per the discussion in the comments below, you can get pretty much the non-tomato-sauce recipe results wanted by using [this "tomato sauce" without tomatoes search](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&tbs=rcp%3A1%2Crcp_ing0%3A-tomatoes&q=%22tomato+sauce%22).

Comment: Which lists recipes to produce tomato sauce rather than recipes that use tomato sauce.

Comment: If you try a search with _tomato sauce_, you do indeed get recipies to produce tomato sauce.  Compare those results with the results from searching for _recipes using tomato sauce_ and you should see results with tomato sauce as an ingredient, such as "Spanish Rice", "Herbed Chicken Tenders with Tomato Sauce", etc.  Also, before using the "Recipes" button, results like "Recipes Using Tomato Sauce - Ask.com" show up.  Mixed in, of course, are recipes _for_ tomato sauce.

Comment: Additionally, after doing the above, you can check "No" for "tomatoes" on the left, and this will effectively remove the tomato sauce recipes from the results.

Answer (score 0):

This is how the URL looks after I submitted the keyword "tomato sauce" from the starting page - http://www.google.com/search?q=tomato+sauce&tbs=rcp%3A1

It shows a relatively bigger list of ingredients this way.

Comment: Which lists recipes to create tomato sauce rather than recipes that use tomato sauce.

Comment: True, but if you move beyond the first few pages, you may find something like "Calamari in Red Wine and Tomato Sauce" & "Mussels in Spicy Tomato Sauce"